# Hover over link, image grayscale filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grayscale

I have an image with a link on top of it. When i hover over the link, the image must be in grayscale. Here's a screenshot (with the image in color). So when i hover over 'BEKIJK REALISATIES' the image (in the background) must be in grayscale.

I'm working in CMS concrete5, so editing the html is not an option (restrictions).

[image]

This is the code in javascript (that's not working).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".image1").css.style.filter = "grayscale(1)";
  });
});
```

Edit: here is the html and css

```css
.link1 a{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    background-color: #3c3c3b;
    color: black !important;
}

.link1 {
    margin-top: -120px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 82px;
}

.image1:hover{
-ms-filter: grayscale(1);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
-moz-filter: grayscale(1);
-o-filter: grayscale(1);
filter: grayscale(1);

}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">

  <div class="image1">
    <a href="http://grafomantestsite2.be/index.php/realisaties">
      <img src="http://grafomantestsite2.be/application/files/6314/4161/6181/realisatie1.png" alt="realisatie1.png" width="401" height="269" class="ccm-image-block img-responsive bID-83">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="link1">
    <p><a href="http://grafomantestsite2.be/index.php/realisaties">BEKIJK REALISATIES</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldnt you rather be using this: `$(".image1").css({"filter":"grayscale(1)", "-moz-filter":"grayscale(1)", "-webkit-filter":"grayscale(1)"});` ...?

Comment: you can easily do it with **CSS** too..

Comment: Could you give us the HTML of you element? I'm sure that we could do this ony with CSS without any JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ujw9opob/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("img").addClass("addingGrayScale");
  });
    $(".link1").mouseleave(function() {
    $("img").removeClass("addingGrayScale");
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.addingGrayScale {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    filter: grayscale(1); /* W3C */
}
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you can't alter the html, doing it with pure css is trick (since i dont know how link1 is structured with regards to image1). That said, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/drunkwolf/4xrdgqqf/) is a working fiddle of what you want.

It uses the cross browser way to do this taken from [here](http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html), which uses the css classes:

```
img.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
```

and

```
img.grayscale.disabled {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale");
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

and implements it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link1")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $(".image1").addClass('grayscale').removeClass('disabled');
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(".image1").addClass('disabled');
  });
});
```